# Find and replace text in string

Tags: python

How can I get `https://onion-rip.de` from

https://onion-rip.de/data/images/9d5faef5c26f69546f8/68c8a2a5fe0a9c5c221a2bb.jpg

and replace with `https://test.de`. Output should be:

https://test.de/data/images/9d5faef5c26f69546f8/68c8a2a5fe0a9c5c221a2bb.jpg

Is any special function in Python for this?

Comment: Basic Python and there's examples all over the internet. Try `str.replace(x, y)` for instance. Almost any language has a string replacement function.

Comment: Please, do not ask questions whose answer can be found with a single internet search or simply by looking at the documentation.

Comment: show what you have tried first. You'll get help from there ...

Comment: Honestly, do not ask this kind of questions here. The answer is so easily accesible by Googling. Take a look at Python's documentation about [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) and [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use Python's `.replace()` like in the following example:

```
x = "Hello world!"
y = x.replace("Hello", "Bye")
print y #Will print out "Bye World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `replace()` method to do this:

```
oldUrl = 'https://onion-rip.de/data/images/9d5faef5c26f69546f8/68c8a2a5fe0a9c5c221a2bb.jpg'
newUrl = oldUrl.replace('https://onion-rip.de', 'https://test.de')
print(newUrl)
```